# How can I have text/objects stay in a div element? (Having the div "stretch" so all of the content will stay inside?)

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, oembed

With Internet Explorer when I have an effect with jQuery (slidedown) or a youtube video or something with oembed it will overlap or overflow over the text/content below. How can I have it so the div will "stretch so all of the text or video will stay inside the element?

[image: You can see in IE the youtube link (oembed) goes outside of the div bringing the text with it, but in chrome it will all stay in the div]

Comment: Html + CSS and you're good to go right? Nope, not with Internet Explorer around. It's an entirely separate art in itself to build websites that are cross-browser compatible, progressively enhance and are still aesthetically congruent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the generated DOM which is quite messy for Firefox and nothing like what's generated for Chrome. I suspect the curvy corners JavaScript and I'd suggest getting that out of the picture to confirm and then taking it up with the developer.

Comment: there is no absolute position... what do you mean?

Comment: @Pete - Ah, I see, I was looking at the DOM *after* scripts had run. Check it out in Firebug on Firefox, you'll see that the DOM generated is very different from that in Chrome. That's causing the problem, I"m not sure where the problem lies - probably with the curvy corners JS. Try removing that script and see if it that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 7 prefers certain elements have 'containers,' I'm not entirely sure why--but I've ran into the issue while trying to animate transparent PNG opacity in IE7.

Inside `Dream.html` the flash object (your video):

`<object width="395" height="321">.. .. ..</object>`

Should have a `div` around it, something like:

```
<div id="video_stage">  
     <object width="395" height="321">.. .. ..</object>
</div>
```

You don't have to give it an `id` but it's nice to keep things fairly semantic--plus just like commenting your code, it's a helpful when coming back to it.

. . .

I tested this, and it works in IE7/IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing floats explicitly after the `<object>`. Something like this:

```
<object...> ... </object>
<div style="clear: both;"></div> <!-- added -->
```